# Count word frequency of all words in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text, nltk

I have a text file, from which I have removed symbols and stop words.

I have also tokenized it (broken it into a list of all words) in case operations are easier with a list.

I would like to create a `.csv` file with frequencies of all words (long format) in descending order. How could I go about it?

I have thought about looping through the list thus:

```
longData = pandas.DataFrame([], index=[], columns=['Frequency'])
for word in tokenizedFile:
    if word in longData.index:
         longData.loc[word]=longData.loc[word]+1
    else:
         wordFrame = pandas.DataFrame([1], index=[word])
         longData.append(wordFrame)
```

but that seems pretty inefficient and wasteful.

Comment: Your solution works?

Comment: Thinking aloud here but I think:
`words =list(set(toknizedFile))`, then 
`tokens = np.asarray(tokenizedFile)`, then you iterate (`for word in words:`) and calculate the number of instances per word `num_instances = length(np.where(tokens == word))`
You can start making a dictionary or a df to store the number of instances for each word

Answer (score 1):

Counter would be good here:

```
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(tokenizedFile)
    longData = pd.DataFrame(c.values(), index = c.keys(), columns=['Frequency'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you text is a list of strings like these above:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text


texts = [
        'this is the first text',
        'this is the secound text',
        'and this is the last text the have two word text'


        ]


#istantiate.
cv = text.CountVectorizer()



cv.fit(texts)


vectors = cv.transform(texts).toarray()
```

you will need explore more the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Series.str.extractall()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Assume `file.txt` is the file-path with texts removed symbols and stop words:

```
# read file into one column dataframe, the default column name is '0'
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\n', header=None)

# extract words into rows and then do value_counts()
words_count = df[0].str.extractall(r'(\w+)')[0].value_counts()
```

The above result `words_count` is a Series which you can convert to dataframe by:

```
df_new = words_count.to_frame('words_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with this, you could try the following method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"words": tokenizedFile.lower()})
value_count = pd.value_counts(df["words"])  # getting the count of all the words
# storing the words and its respective count in a new dataframe
# value_count.keys() are the words, value_count.values is the count
vocabulary_df = pd.DataFrame({"words": value_count.keys(), "count": value_count.values})
```

What this does is,

1. take the list of words (`tokenizedFile`), and convert all the words to lowercase. And then, create a column with title `words` and the data will be all the words from the file.
2. The `value_count` variable will store the number of times each word appears in our df dataframe by making use of the `value_counts` method available for dataframes. It sorts it by default in descending order of the count.
3. Our final line of code creates a new `vocabulary_df` that will store all the words and it's count nicely into a new dataframe (`value_count` is saved as a Series type). Here, `value_count.keys()` has the words, and `value_count.values` has the count of each word.

Hopefully, this will be helpful to someone along the line. :)